# Transfer files between 2 inspirons linked directly via Ethernet cable

Tags: ethernet, dell-inspiron

I recently got an Inspiron 7559 and I started to transfer files from my old Inspiron 5447 over Wi-Fi.

Do I need a **crossover** cable to transfer files from one to the other using a direct Ethernet connection between the two laptops or can I use a standard Ethernet cable?

Answer (score 3):

I assume that by "crossfire" you meant a "crossover" cable. The answer is "no", you don't need a crossover cable. Because your Inspiron 7559 has a gigabit Ethernet port, and nearly all gigabit ports support Auto MDI-X (though not required by standard), a straight-through cable should work.

You will, however, need to manually configure your IP settings for each interface since a DHCP server won't be available on a direct connection.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a network switch and want to connect the two computers directly, then yes, you will need a cross**over** (not crossfire) cable. The individual wires are arranged differently in a crossover cable to enable the signal to "crossover" without a switch, so a regular Ethernet cable will not work.

Edit: @Google Fail raises a good point in his answer; I forgot about Auto-MDIX. You may be fine with a regular cable, after all.

Comment: I did mean crossover. I'll try it out when i get home. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like i can connect without having to set up special settings. Turned off the recieving laptop's wifi and connected it via ethernet and its transfering at 60 to 80 mbps.

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you. Mark Google Fail's answer so others who have this question can see it, and to give them credit!